# Membershi plugin : Can I use custom page for user login?

Tags: wordpress, membership

Dear Wordpress developers,

First of all I must say I'm new to wordpress themes development.

I'm creating a membership site using [Membership plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/membership/). I created the site and all other pages Account, Register, Subscriptions...etc. But I noticed that, the login page for the users( I mean, the people who paid and became members in certain levels; Premium, Basic..etc.) is just the standard WordPress admin login page. And the user's profile page is very similar to the administrator dashboard. So, that's the problem.

Can I add my own custom pages for those page ? So that I can personalize them similar to the site theme. (But I need the standard login page for me and other admins)

I hope I made it clear for you... So, please help me...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by  [Theme My login](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) plugin, you can customize the login page as same as your theme, and you can redirect the user based on their role, and etc

Comment: Thanks Jothikannan.... It worked for me. I love to vote your answer but, I don't have reputation level since I'm very new to this site. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, you create your own login form and set action of form like this:

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://yourdomain.com/wp-login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" value=""/>
<input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" value="" />
```

keep the names of fields intact , then you it will be working right away

Comment: Thanks shashikant... However your answer didn't work as I wanted to customize only the user's login page. Not every login page including admin's. Anyway, I appreciate you for answering. Thanks.